# How to lock out concurrent users from accessing a page related to data from a database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, locking

I have an application, written in C#.NET, where users input, edit, and delete incidents accessing a database created with SQL Server. The application uses a search page to populate various rows from the search query into a datagrid, then once selected the user is able to press an update button which in turn proceeds to another page where the data is populated into a form for editing, which is where my problem is. I'm trying to implement a locking mechanism so that when a user accesses a row from the database, another user won't be able to pull up that same page. Currently I have implemented several transactions to each stored procedure that the page is calling thinking that would do the trick, but alas, each stored procedure is being called separately when the page loads, then closes after it populates the data, so there is no way of locking out through there. Which comes to my next thought, of trying to make this locked out to concurrent users when this particular page loads. The main stored procedure that populates the page calls on an IncidentID to retrieve the data, so is there a way of checking to see if this ID is being used in the Page_Load? I'm still entry level with a huge head on my shoulders, so a lot of this implementation I'm learning through here and other web pages, but I haven't found anything to help just yet... The code is pretty lengthy but if you need any to reference just let me know. TIA

EDIT: Here is some code. I'm using SSMS so the semicolons are added for me. These are tests but with the exact syntax...
Query to populate the form with data

```
USE [Test_Live]
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_SelectIncident_ByCaseNumberUpdate]
(
    @IncidentID int
)
AS
BEGIN TRANSACTION
SELECT i.IncidentID,
i.PersonID,
i.BusInfoID,
i.TypeOfIncident,
i.DateOfIncident,
/* etc. etc. */
FROM tblTestIncident i WITH(ROWLOCK)
left JOIN tblTestPerson p on i.PersonID = p.PersonID
/* some other joins are here */
WHERE i.IncidentID = @IncidentID
COMMIT
```

C# code that populates form with data. The GetConnection() method is within another .dll file that the page is using. it returns the connection string through ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.gIncidentID = Convert.ToInt32(Utils.decryptQueryString(this.Request.QueryString["iid"]));
    try
    {
        this.lblCurrentUser.Text = this.Page.User.Identity.Name.ToUpper();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       this.lblErrors.Text = this.lblErrors.Text + "Unexpected exception in Load: " + ex.Message + ". ";
    }
    this.populateFormWithData(this.gIncidentID);
}

private void populateFormWithData(int incidentID)
{
   SqlConnection connection = this.GetConnection();
   SqlParameter sqlParameter = new SqlParameter("@IncidentID", SqlDbType.Int);
   sqlParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
   sqlParameter.Value = (object)incidentID;
   SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
   sqlDataAdapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand();
   DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
   sqlDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Connection = connection;
   sqlDataAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandText = "sp_SelectIncident_ByCaseNumberUpdate";
   sqlDataAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
   sqlDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(sqlParameter);
   sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dataSet, "Incident");
   if (dataSet.Tables["Incident"].Rows.Count > 0)
   {
      //code that fills in all fields within the page
   }
   else
   {
      this.lblCaseNumberData.ForeColor.Equals((object)"Red");
      this.lblCaseNumberData.Text = "No Case data found!";
   }
   //this is where I think the problem is as to why the transactions aren't working
   connection.Close();
}
```

I hope this helps...

Comment: Based on your ask and its inherent complexity, please post what you have tried.

Comment: Just added some code to better understand. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Locking data like this can be problematic. Users can keep a page open and leave for the day.
The data will be locked until they return. You would be better off adding a TimeStamp column to your tables and checking if it has changed before updating. If the TimeStamp has changed, inform the user and reload the data.

See here for an example:

[SQL Server optimistic locking - Returning changed timestamp value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5312847/sql-server-optimistic-locking-returning-changed-timestamp-value/5312919#5312919)

TimeStamp/RowVersion info:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm actually already going to be implementing a timestamp feature with it's own section, which is another specification. The intranet app already boots the user out if they have left it open for too long. This "locking out" procedure is what they want. Is there any possible way?

Comment: You could add a LockedBy column to the table.
`Update Table set LockedBy = @UserID where IncidentID = @IncidentID and LockedBy is null`
If lock fails (LockedBy was not null) rollback/return.
When finished set LockedBy back to null.
I would recommend doing this at the point of update rather than the read as the table can be immediately unlocked after the update.

Comment: a little late to respond, got tied up with so much work. This is what we're going to do. We've set a flagged column in the database that stores the users name, null by default, then on the page load of the edit case we check if it's null, if not, return a message returning the value in the column, then set the fields to read only. Thanks so much for your help. It took a while to implement but it's working now. Pretty neat stuff!!